# Xcode version in App Store and in Xcode do not match

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store

I am having a strange issue. I need access to Xcode 10 to test my app. So I downloaded and installed the latest version of Xcode from the App Store to my Mac. I have confirmed this in the App Store:

[image: image showing i installed XCode version 10.1 on my mac]

See in the top left in the above image, version 10.1 of Xcode is installed.

But to my frustration when I open Xcode it still is version 9, as shown in this screen shot:

[image: Xcode version still 9.4]

See just below the Xcode logo it says version 9.4.1

What is going on? I tried restarting my computer again but the Xcode version is still 9.4 when i open xcode. Is there somewhere I can choose to use version 10 of Xcode?

Comment: do spotlight search (window+space) and search "Xcode" it will give you all application.

Answer (score 0):

You might have possibly installed multiple xCode applications in your system.

Option 1:

> Select Finder -> Applications

Check if there are multiple xCode applications.

Option 2:

Go to your project folder.

> Right click . xcodeproj or .xcworkspace file -> Open With

This will show all the xCode applications installed in system.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this. Searching Finder -> Applications only shows Xcode 9.4.1 and right clicking the .xcworkspace file only yields the option to open it with Xcode 9.4.1. So annoying.